Failed to start desktop
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 and recently performed the following:

In Firefox, installed UI.Vision RPA script player
Downloaded and installed UI.Vision XModules installer (requires Fuse)
sudo apt upgrade (produced a note about redundant modules)
sudo apt autoremove
reboot

Now the machine is stuck in the boot process. Fortunately, I can still get in through SSH and have found it's stuck in a loop trying to get the desktop going:
2024-12-09T17:01:38.210920+00:00 ROUTEL systemd[1308]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 423.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.219783+00:00 ROUTEL systemd[1308]: Started snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service - Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.266252+00:00 ROUTEL kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1733763698.264:450): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/proc/25301/maps" pid=25301 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2024-12-09T17:01:38.395641+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Failed to do gtk init. Waiting for a new session with desktop capabilities.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.405400+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_35...
2024-12-09T17:01:38.407276+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.407418+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_36...
2024-12-09T17:01:38.408982+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.409170+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33...
2024-12-09T17:01:38.411474+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31...
2024-12-09T17:01:38.413872+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.414061+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_37...
2024-12-09T17:01:38.416584+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.416775+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_34...
2024-12-09T17:01:38.419512+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
2024-12-09T17:01:38.419713+00:00 ROUTEL snapd-desktop-i[25332]: Loop exited. Forcing reload.

It looks like a Apparmor problem so I tried aa-logprof -f /var/log/syslog
This doesn't seem to notice the fault and doesn't change anything.

not an expert on Fuse but these two refs may be of some help and relevance perhaps https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1cmgjfb/ubuntu_2404_not_booting_after_installing_fuse/ and complete guide installing Fuse

You got it in one, Graham! I had, indeed, installed the wrong Fuse. I have reinstalled the ubuntu-desktop, the correct fuse and now we are all hunky dory. Many thanks.

you should answer your own question in that case with the steps you took to rectify after which you can accept it which may help someone else with this issue. See https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

This turned out to be because I used the wrong Fuse. To recover, from a terminal I did:

sudo apt remove fuse
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install libfuse2t64
sudo shutdown -r

